# Using python simple-salesforce is there a way to query logically deleted records?

Tags: python, merge, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

Is there a way to query Salesforce records that have been deleted, using python simple-salesforce?  In other words can it do this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE isDeleted=true and masterRecordId != null 
  AND SystemModstamp > 2006-01-01T23:01:01+01:00
```

This query is what Salesforce suggests to know when two records have been merged.

While the simple-salesforce deleted() method returns a list of ids deleted, it does not give the masterRecordId.

The Salesforce restful api supports a 'query_all' to get logically deleted records.  However simple-salesforce's query_all is a wrapper around query() and query_more()

Comment: Do you think that it would be considered metadata on the Contact? There is a function for that but I'm not sure what it returns either.

Comment: No, it is not meta data.  It is records in the Contact Object with the isDeleted set to true (logical deletion).  These records are viewable in the Recycle bin online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag
`include_deleted=True`.
Function defenition is like - `def query(self, query, include_deleted=False, **kwargs)`

You can use the same flag for `query_more`, `query_all`, `query_all_iter` etc ..

Github link - https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py